# ElasticSearch bulk insert/update operation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not sure if I am using correctly the `upsert` operation in bulk indexing.

My request is:

```
{ "update": {"_id": "610946100"}}\n
{"doc": {"id":"610946100","uri":"/0/0/1/6/4/0/610946100.xml"}, "doc_as_upsert" : true}\n
```

and url is: `http://localhost:9200/anIndex/aType/_bulk`

I guess I missed something in the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) but I still can't find how to make this operation.

What I want is to **create the above document in the index or update it if exists.**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you add records in the index via the bulk API as

```
{ "create": {"_id": "someId"}}\n
{"id":"someId","uri":"/0/1/3/2/1/0511912310/511912310.xml"}\n
```

then if the id already exists in the index you will get an exception.
If you want to either add or **replace** a document (depending on whether it exists or not), you should do the request as

```
{ "index": {"_id": "someId"}}\n
{"id":"someId","uri":"/0/1/3/2/1/0511912310/511912310.xml"}\n
```

> create will fail if a document with the same index and type exists
> already, whereas index will add or replace a document as necessary
>
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html version 5.3

Answer (score 9):

The only thing I see that differs between your request and the [Bulk Documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk) is that the examples have the index and type defined in the update action. So based on this I would try adding those values like the following.

```
{"update": {"_id": "610946100", "_type": "aType", "_index": "anIndex"}}\n
{"doc": {"uri":"/0/0/1/6/4/0/610946100.xml"}, "doc_as_upsert" : true}\n
```

Additionally since you are specifying the document `_id` in the update command, I would remove it from the partial document, or mark it as `_id`. (You were missing the underscore)