# Where do additional action paramters go in the ElasticSearch bulk api?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building a data backfill script for random dataloss in elasticSearch. I only want to add missing documents in an index from the backup; new versions may already exist and I don't want to lose any updates.

The elasticSearch index api allows me to specify the OpType to not update records: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-index
e.g. `[opType=create]`

and I'm trying to use the bulk api to make it more efficient: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/docs-bulk.html

What I can't figure out is where to put the 'opType' in the bulk api.

is it in the metadata field so it looks like the following?

`{ 'index': { '_index': indexName, '_type': 'data', '_id': <my Id>, 'opType': 'create' } }
{data for item}`

or do I put it somewhere else?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651596/elasticsearch-bulk-insert-update-operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the link you refer to, if you want to use the same semantics as `opType: create` you need to use the `create` command instead of the `index` one:

```
 change this
      |
      v
{ 'create': { '_index': indexName, '_type': 'data', '_id': <my Id>} }
{ data for item }
```

Comment: Thanks,  I must have been focusing on something else when I read that.